# How to change the color of specific calendars?

Tags: calendar, samsung-touchwiz, google-calendar

I'm using the default calendar application that came with my phone (Samsung Galaxy S 2), which is kept in sync with Google Calendar. I have multiple calendars there, but I was not able to find a way to change the colors of specific calendars, which is unfortunate as calendar #1 and #5 share almost precisely the same color by default. Those are *not* the same color I see in the online Google Calendar.

Is there a way to control the colors of specific calendars, or is there a similar, alternate calendar or tool I can use that will allow me to do so?

Comment: Mine appear to match the colors I use in the web version of Google Calendar.

Comment: @AlEverett maybe my device uses a different calendar app by default?

Comment: Perhaps. Mine is an original Droid.

Comment: @AlEverett is there any way I can check which application is used as my calendar? Wasn't able to find it in the application manager.

Comment: Mine also matches the colors that I use in Google calendar on the web

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the problem seemed to have gone away on its own after a few more synchronizations, so I guess the solution is to just wait a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Samsung has their own Calendar in TouchWiz, it is not the "Stock" calendar. And from what I remember, you cant change the color of the calendars in the TouchWiz calendar. I stopped using the touchwiz calendar and bought "[Business Calendar](https://market.android.com/details?id=mikado.bizcalpro)" - there is a [free version](https://market.android.com/details?id=netgenius.bizcal) too that has ads and missing a couple features like "drag&drop". It works great, and has a good home screen widget too.

I used it as a replacement for the limited calendar in touchwiz, and now that I have a ROM that has the "stock" calendar, I still use it.

[image: bizcalendar]